# use different name for docker-compose.yml in AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Docker Amazon Linux 2 Platform)

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to use [Docker Amazon Linux 2 Platform](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-multicontainer-migration.html)
 with my AWS Elastic Beanstalk

I want to use now  supported `docker-compose.yml`  but I want to use different name e.g. : `docker-compose-server.yml`

Is there a way how to tell that to EB ? e.g. with .ebextensions ?